# How do I setup a static tf?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I want to set up a static transform from my kinect frame to my robot frame and I am finding that this method is too slow:

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    try{
listener.waitForTransform("/base_link","/camera_depth_optical_frame",ros::Time::now(),ros::Duration(3));
        listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/camera_depth_optical_frame",ros::Time::now(), transform);
        }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
        ROS_WARN("Base to camera transform unavailable %s", ex.what());
        }
```

Since the transformation is static I tried to make transform a global variable in my program and use it in different places but I get a compiling error from this saying something along the lines of:

```
error: reference to ‘transform’ is ambiguous
```

How do I set up a static transform during an initialization part of a program so that I don't keep processing the same transformation over and over?

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57355/how-do-i-setup-a-static-tf?/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-07**:
You're doing the right thing (if the above code is run once). The error you are getting seems related to your code. Either you have another `transform` defined somewhere else or you are using the same code multiple times (by copying or implicitly). How to do it correctly depends on your software.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-07**:
Hey dornhege, I don't think I've defined it multiple times but I defined listener and transform as global variables and run an initialization and then just call the transform in my callback. I will try to figure this out and get back to you! thank you for the reply

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-07**:
@MartinW, apart from compilation problem, what do you mean by saying "this method is too slow"?

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-08**:
I am trying to run a real-time system that uses the kinect, does some processing on the point cloud and then feeds this information to a robot running at 10Hz. But adding this transformation really slows it down for some reason, if I comment it out I run at approximately the speed I want though!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-08**:
If you don't want to cache the transform, one thing might be to use `ros::Time(0)` instead of `ros::Time::now()`. Whatever now is, the listener will always have to wait until the message from time=now arrives. With Time(0) it will just take the last one (which I guess is what you want).

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-07-25**:
Are you trying to publish the base_link->camera tf in the fovis package using the kinect? have you been able to do it? I'm still trying to implement this tf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To setup transform between frames you have to **broadcast** (publish) transform instead of listening to it.

There are two ways to do that:

1. Use [static_transform_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher) -- this one is a ready to use node, that you can run from command line.
2. Use [tf::TransformBroadcaster](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) -- to create transforms in a code.

**EDIT**: If the transform is already exist you can simply listen to it once outside of publishing cycle.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-07**:
Hey Boris, In my urdf I have defined the joint and link connections (and thereby the transform), so do I still need to use a static transform publisher? It just seems like more work/system resources to add this, I just want my program to find this transform once, and reuse it to keepup program speed

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-07**:
If you are using `robot_state_publisher`, then it will publish `tf` tree from URDF. So no need for additional transform publisher.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-08**:
I am using robot_state_publisher, so is there a way to obtain transforms from this? Or is the method above doing this implicitly?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-08**:
Yes, that is it.